# how to do zoom image like facebook and tagging name?

Tags: android, image-processing, zooming, tagging

I am new in `android` ,i want to do zoom `image` and tagging name on actual  position on `image`.if I zoom image then position of `tagged text` should not change.`tagged text` would stick with in  position on `image`.

***Help me.thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 1):

You can check position like this way,

```
 mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
        } 
});
```

For demo purpose,check demo git  **[SimpleTagImageView](https://github.com/wujingchao/SimpleTagImageView)**

Comment: I seen SimpleTagImageView demo.but ,I want to tag username over image co-ordinate position Like Facebook tagging.